# Can I bridge Swift structs `as` C structs?

Tags: c, swift

I have a C struct.

```
typedef struct Vector2 {
  float x;
  float y;
} Vector2;
```

When used in Swift its members become immutable, so I've written a Swift counterpart that conforms to Equatable, supports arithmetic operators, etc.

```swift
struct Vector {
  var x: Float
  var y: Float
}
```

In order to use the Swift type as a substitute argument in C methods, I need to bridge it somehow.

I realize I could have a computed property on my Swift type `.vector2: Vector2 {}`, but I'd prefer to use the `as` keyword.

Is this possible?
`swiftVector as Vector2`

Comment: Does this help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using-imported-c-structs-and-unions-in-swift

Comment: Can you share how you're importing the C struct into Swift? C structs import by default with _mutable_ members, and using your exact `Vector2` definition, I confirmed that the members imported as `var`s and not `let`s. Can you share a snippet of code showing how you're trying to use `Vector2` in Swift that highlights the immutability issue?

Comment: Ahh it is mutable after all haha. Somehow I had gotten it into my mind that they were imported immutably. And as for the original question of the `as` keyword, the documentation doesn't ever mention it, so I'm assuming that Swift simply doesn't allow/support it.